# Splash Screen showing non-related layout view instead of splash layout view post migrating to Android R8 on debug mode

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, splash-screen, android-r8

Splash screen showing non-related layout view instead of splash layout view.

This occurred after migrating to Android R8 from ProGuard with Android Studio 3.5.1 and Gradle Plug-in 3.5.1 with (minifyEnabled & shrinkResources enabled with proguard-android-optimize.txt)  when moved from dev build variant to prod build on debug mode.

This behaviour occurred once only and on changing to non-optimised mode and vice-versa the issue didn't occur again. Such behaviour has never occurred earlier.

Has anyone had similar experience?

Is it related to android R8?

Please assist.

Comment: Have you tried to set `shrinkResources ` and/or `minifyEnabled` is set to `false`, to see if turning one of the two off makes a difference? You also mention that it "occurred once only" - does it go away if you rebuild the project through the IDE or command line `./gradlew clean assembleRelease` without switching between debug/release?

Comment: Yes we tried by disabling minifyEnabled & shrinkResources to false along with ProGuard non optimise mode. It works well on it and after re-enabling back to ProGuard optimised mode it work ok. Also tried Gradle clean.. The issue was not repeated.. but sure will this behaviour show up again on any device.

Comment: If you see it again, please try a full rebuild (e.g. ´./gradlew clean <target>´). If that solves the issue it could be an issue with dependency tracking in the gradle build.

Comment: Thanks. Will surely update if occurs again.